# php recive array from get form

Tags: php, arrays, forms

how can i recive an array from an html get form?

i would receive the value of same checkbox, they have all the same name "es. object"

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML form, use something like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="object[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="object[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="object[]" />
```

Then when you receive it in PHP the values of the checkboxes will be held in the array $object.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'm completely understanding your question but if you name your elements in the following way they will become ad array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="lang[ ]" value="en">English<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="lang[ ]" value="fr">Français<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="lang[ ]" value="es">Español<br />
```

Answer (score -1):

<strike>PHP puts all data received from a get form into the array $_GET</strike>

Put this on your page

```
print_r($_GET);
```

misunderstood the question